# Kruskal wallis and posthoc test verification?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

I am trying to run a kruskal-wallis test on my dataset.

Dataset is given below:

```r
condition <- c("hitBeforeSuction", "hitBeforeSuction",   
    "hitBeforeSuction", "hitBeforeSuction", "hitBeforeSuction",
    "hitAfterSuction", "hitAfterSuction", "hitAfterSuction",  
    "hitAfterSuction", "hitAfterSuction",
    "FAbeforeSuction", "FAbeforeSuction", "FAbeforeSuction", 
    "FAbeforeSuction", "FAbeforeSuction", "FAafterSuction", 
    "FAafterSuction", "FAafterSuction", "FAafterSuction", 
    "FAafterSuction")

rate <- c(0.8426, 0.9425, 0.8184, 0.9989, 0.9021, 0.9732, 0.8723, 
    0.6944, 0.9770, 0.8985, 0.3460, 0.0902, 0.3581, 0.0988, 0.2911, 
    0.8696, 0.7789, 0.5446, 0.9579, 0.8263)

statsMatrix <- data.frame(rate, condition)
```

I'm curious if there are differences in the rate amongst the conditions. You will notice that my sample size isn't big (n = 5) and I wonder if this is why I am getting these results.

If I plot the boxplot of my data:

[image]

I expect to see the difference between the orange (FAbeforeSuction) and the pink condition (FAafterSuction).

I ran kruskal-wallis and then dunn's posthoc test on the dataset.

```r
kruskal.test(rate ~ condition, data=statsMatrix)
```

in which I get a significant p < 0.05. This is good.

```r
    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  rate by condition
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 11.949, df = 3, p-value = 0.007561
```

I tried two difference types of dunn's test. First:

```r
require(FSA)
PT = dunnTest(rate~condition, data=statsMatrix, method="bh")
PT
```

```r
Comparison
FAafterSuction - FAbeforeSuction    2.0311854   0.042236187 0.084472374 
FAafterSuction - hitAfterSuction    -0.9621405  0.335979047 0.403174856 
FAbeforeSuction - hitAfterSuction   -2.9933259  0.002759549 0.008278647 
FAafterSuction - hitBeforeSuction   -0.9621405  0.335979047 0.503968571 
FAbeforeSuction - hitBeforeSuction  -2.9933259  0.002759549 0.016557294 
hitAfterSuction - hitBeforeSuction  0.0000000   1.000000000 1.000000000
```

The result I am looking for is on the 1st row and I see that this is not significant when p-adjusted! (3rd column).

I tried a difference version of dunn's test because I wasn't sure if this was the correct version

```r
require(ggstatsplot)
ggbetweenstats(data = statsMatrix, y = rate, x = condition, 
    type = "nonparametric")
```

[image]

and I see the similar results! p-value is provided on the top.

```r
PT = kwAllPairsDunnTest(rate ~ condition, data=statsMatrix, 
    p.adjust.method = "holm")
PT
```

```r
    Pairwise comparisons using Dunn's all-pairs test

data: rate by condition

                hitBeforeSuction hitAfterSuction FAbeforeSuction
hitAfterSuction 1.000            -               -              
FAbeforeSuction 0.017            0.017           -              
FAafterSuction  1.000            1.000           0.169          

P value adjustment method: holm
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

How do I understand the "seemingly inconsistent" result between my data visualization and kruskal-wallis test? For such a small sample size (n = 5), is there also a better test I could use?

Comment: The inconsistency is due to p-value adjustments in post-hoc comparisons, which are not applied to the omnibus K-W. But your sample size is also extremely small, my advise would be to collect more data points rather than try to find a test that gives you a significant result.